# http://localhost/richmedia/format/?id=Jazz-Cash-HTML-5-Polite-Billboard "want to remove ?id= from URL"

Tags: .htaccess

Hi there i am working on SEO friendly URLs here is who my url look alike

> http://localhost/richmedia/format/?id=Jazz-Cash-HTML-5-Polite-Billboard

This is the part where i am sending request with get method

```
  <form method="GET" action="format/" target="_blank">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Preview</button> 

                      <input type="hidden" value="'.$seo_title.'" name="id">
                </form>
```

this is what i write in .htacces file

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^creative-zone$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^agencies$ agencies.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^advertisers$ advertisers.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^format/?$ format.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)format/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ format.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

i want to remove this "?id="section from my url. Every Thing is working fine But this ?id= need to be fixex. Need Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like your last rule should work, it may be an issue of troubleshooting the `(.*)format` part?

Comment: Thanks Mate i Have accomplished the task by converting <button> with anchor<a> tag as you said that the value was passing with get and it has to be changed. Everything remains same only button tag is replaced with anchor tag. Thanks For Your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make sure the application still handles the parameter correctly but the answer is fairly straight forward:

`RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_-])?$ index.php?yourparam=$1 [NC,L]`

In other words, look for a string after the root, then convert that to an id on the server side.

However when generating the links you'll need to address the id= 'thing'

Your links might look like
`<a href="my_foo_bar" title="click to see my foo bar">link to stuff</a>`

which would then be converted to

`?id=my_foo_bar`